# Как сделать скрипт меню выбора сессии в Tmux?

Tags: linux, bash, сессия, tmux, .bashrc

У меня есть скрипт .bashrc автозапуска tmux при подключении по ssh, который автоматически подключает меня к предыдущей сессии:

```
if [ "$PS1" != "" -a "${STARTED_TMUX:-x}" = x -a "${SSH_TTY:-x}" != x ]
then
        STARTED_TMUX=1; export STARTED_TMUX
        sleep 1
        ( (tmux has-session -t remote && tmux attach-session -t remote) || (tmux new-session -s remote) ) && exit 0
        echo "tmux failed to start"
fi
```

Как дополнить этот скрипт, чтобы он при каждом новом подключении предлагал запустить новый сеанс или подключиться к уже существующему сеансу? Как меню выбора.
Хотелось бы иметь простое меню для подключения к существующей сессии (или сессиям) или создания новой.